# Navbar Links not appearing when resizing screen

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I am trying to create a Navbar that hides the links and shows "fas fa-bars fa-1x" Icon (3 horizontal bars) the when smaller than an "md" size screen. When the screen becomes smaller, the button appears but does not work when it is clicked.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mmsyed/z8vg749t/6/#&togetherjs=MJCCM4wefa

I have removed all custom CSS and JS
Looked at the Bootstrap 4 reference pages

It works when the 2nd "" is removed,

Take a look at the fiddle...

```
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!--jQuery  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-i1LQnF23gykqWXg6jxC2ZbCbUMxyw5gLZY6UiUS98LYV5unm8GWmfkIS6jqJfb4E" crossorigin="anonymous"
</head>
<body>
<nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-md">

<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <img src="images/logo.png" width="70" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Navbar  </a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse">
<span class=""><i class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span>
</button>

<!-- Collapsable Content -->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">

  <!-- Left Side -->

<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle disabled" id="" data-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu"> 
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- Right Side -->


<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
  <!-- Left Side Links and Icons -->
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="toggler">
      <i class="fab fa-rebel"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href=#" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
    </a>

  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
   </a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href=#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing tag on the `dropdown-menu` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things going wrong, which are:

1. you did't specify `data-target` in your `<button class="navbar-toggler" >... </button>`
2. `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="">` needs an ID which would be the same as `data-target` (from point 1 above)
3. you had disabled the dropdown using the class `disabled` in your code: `<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle disabled">... </a>`
4. didn't include `bootstrap.min.js`
5. didn't close the script tag for `Font Awesome`
6. incorrect/incomplete quotes for multiple elements check `nav-item` for LinkedIn and Twitter

following **snippet** works with these specific fixes:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MustaphaSyedDM.css" />
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--jQuery  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-i1LQnF23gykqWXg6jxC2ZbCbUMxyw5gLZY6UiUS98LYV5unm8GWmfkIS6jqJfb4E" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="mb-1 navbar navbar-expand-md">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="70" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Navbar
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"> 
            <span class=""><i class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span>
        </button>

  <!-- Collapsable Content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">

    <!-- Left Side -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Example</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right Side -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">

      <!-- Left Side Links and Icons -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="toggler">
          <i class="far fa-address-card"></i> </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">
          <i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```